# System.IO.Abstractions usage

Tags: c#, unit-testing, file-io, io

I'm writing some unit tests using System.IO.Abstractions following the sample code in GitHub and got stuck here:

```
fileSystem: new FileSystem() //use default implementation which calls System.IO
```

This line is meant to initialise System.IO.FileSystem but that class does not exist... do you know if it has been deprecated or am I getting this wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: did you put `using System.IO.Abstractions;` at the top of your file?

Comment: Yes, I did. My question is: the non-testing initializer should create an instance of the "regular" FileSystem, right?

Answer (score 11):

yes, in the production code, you should inject an instance of `System.IO.Abstractions.FileSystem`. In your test code an instance of `System.IO.Abstractions.TestingHelpers.MockFileSystem`.

Comment: Clarification for future readers: Since they are abstractions, the type you insert shouldn't matter. In other words, you can certainly insert an instance of the ''regular' file system. But your production code should certainly accept classes within the System.IO.Abstractions.FileSystem dll as parameters, rather than the 'regular' file system classes.

Comment: But to be clear, we have to literally change the imported namespaces in our production code just to allow for unit testing... seems anti-pattern to me

Comment: @fullStackChris If you have System.IO usings, perhaps that is the anti-pattern. That is hard-coding against a specific filesystem IO implementation, rather than depending on an abstraction. By making the change to System.IO.Abstractions, you are actually fixing that.